# Parsing CSV Into JSON [Python]

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a csv file with this plaintext:

```
h1,,,h2,,,h3,,,h4,,,h5,,,h6,,
s1,s2,s3,s1,s2,s3,s1,s2,s3,s1,s2,s3,s1,s2,s3,s1,s2,s3
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6
7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7
8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8
9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9
```

The first row (h1, h2, ..., h6) are the main headers and the second row (s1, ..., s2) are the subheaders with the values being the numbers 1 - 9. This is what I have so far in terms of python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import json
import os
from os import path
import sys

arg = sys.argv[1]

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'invalid number of arguments'
    sys.exit()

with open(arg, "r") as sheet:
    s = csv.reader(sheet)
    for row in s:
        print row
```

I want my json string to look like this:

```
{
    "h1": {
        "s1": [1, 2, ..., 9],
        "s2": [1, 2, ..., 9],
        "s3": [1, 2, ..., 9]
    },
    # etc
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Boilerplate code to print a `csv` doesn't really qualify as effort shown.  Have you tried anything actually relating to your problem?

Comment: I've tried parsing it manually as a python string, but wanted to know if the csv module for python has any formatting features that could be of some use to me

Comment: You want to use pandas. Pandas sees data files in this hierarchal columnar style you see here. Once it is in pandas, it will be easier to turn it into a json format by Series. There isn't enough space in this comment box to copy the entire manual for pandas.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and get back to you once it works out for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

with open(arg, "r") as sheet:
    s = csv.reader(sheet)
    main_header = next(s)
    sub_header = next(s)
    result = {}
    for row in s:
        aheader = None
        for main, sub, value in zip(main_header, sub_header, row):
            if not main:
                main = aheader
            result.setdefault(main, {}).setdefault(sub, []).append(value)
            aheader = main

print (result)
```